# Module ID not appearing in Gii?

Tags: yii2, yii-modules

I am not getting Module ID as shown in the Youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtHB58-JA38 , 7:33

I am a beginner in Yii, and would be thankful for the responses.

[image]

I mean, I am not able to create a CRUD specific to a module

After creating a Module, how to create CRUD for a module using Gii ?

Comment: Explain better .. or you think we shoudl look at all the video and imagine what you need?

Comment: I mean, I am not able to create a CRUD specific to a module.

Comment: After creating a Module, how to use the module in Gii ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the view as `backend\modules\settings\views\companies`. By doing that, I got the same files as mentioned in the code file.

Comment: @backend/modules/settings/views/companies

Answer (score 0):

If you need relate to the settings module in crud for create the normal CRUD view

in the Module id you should digit

```
 settings
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted; just that I am not getting the input to enter the Module ID.

Comment: Why ? .. if you setted the module in config .. and create the module directory and create all the value above setting with module

Comment: This is the defualt mask .. and is showed for normal crud  if you add module  when indicate in video when all the element are setting properly the you see also the field module ID .. (see the video again)

Comment: You must create module   ... model inside module test if module index work and the crud for the module controller and view..

Comment: I have added the module in `backend/config/main.php`,     ` 'modules' => [
        'settings' => [
                    'class' => 'backend\modules\settings\Settings',
                ],
    ],`
and have the module directory `backend/modules/settings/` and had used GII's module generator.

Comment: Have you create the class ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101812/discussion-between-maan81-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 0):

@app/modules/settings/views/(view name)  in view path , we will get same result

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing, you have just add an '@' on the beginning of the view path :

```
@backend\modules\settings\views\companies
```

Answer (score 0):

> **It Worked for me**

Model Class : `backend\modules\students\models\Pdf`

Search Model Class : `backend\modules\students\models\PdfSearch`

Controller Class : `backend\modules\students\controllers\PdfController`

View Path : `@backend\modules\students\views\pdf`

[image: You can use like this]

[image: This is my generated output folders]

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add View Path as:
**backend\modules\settings\views**